# Clean way to find associated values of a stacked bar graph

Tags: d3.js

As a side note, let me remark how thankful I am that there's an active D3.js community here. I've learned a lot in the few times I've posted and hope to only get better.

Let's consider the same data set that I've been using:

**test_data.csv**:

```
date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575
```

and the .html file:

**page.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 -->
<style>
    #tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    #tooltip.hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    #tooltip p {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    rect:hover {
        fill:orange;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Month: </strong><span id="month"></span><p>
    <p><strong>Value: </strong><span id="value"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#CE1126", "#00B6D0"]); // red and blue 

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month

var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
                  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year

var formatNum = d3.format(",")

// load .csv file
d3.csv("test_data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        //console.log(parseDate(d.date));
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
    var barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(data.length+1);     

    data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });


    x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

    var max = x.domain()[1];
    var min = x.domain()[0];
    var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

    x.domain([min,datePlusOneMonth]);

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);


    // the bars 
    g.append("g")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", barWidth)
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {

        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + barWidth / 2;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + height / 2;
        if (d[0] == 0) var value = d[1]; else var value = d[1]-d[0]; // data set values between col_1 and col_2

        //Update the tooltip position and value
        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", xPosition + "px")
          .style("top", yPosition + "px")                       
          .select("#value")
          .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 

        d3.select("#tooltip")
          .style("left", xPosition + "px")
          .style("top", yPosition + "px")                       
          .select("#month")
          .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the value 

        //Show the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

      })
     .on("mouseout", function() {
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);

     });


    // x-axis
    var axis = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);


    const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
    xYearAxis.tickValues([firstDataYear].concat(x.ticks()));

    var yearAxis = g.append("g")
                     .attr("class", "axis")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
                     .call(xYearAxis);

    axis.selectAll("g").select("text")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");

});
</script>

</body>
```

This **does** give me the desired behavior, in that I obtain the associated value with a hover:

[image]

**but** it was done rather messily. Namely:

```
if (d[0] == 0) var value = d[1]; else var value = d[1]-d[0]; // data set values between col_1 and col_2
```

Basically, the code says this: if the base of the bar is on the x-axis, use the height of the bar (in `d[1]`) in the tooltip. Otherwise, use `d[1]-d[0]` (for the bars in blue).

Now that I'm thinking about this, I could have just written

```
var value = d[1]-d[0];
```

but **is there a way to write this so that I can read the code and specifically notice that it's referencing the col_1 and col_2 values, rather than the difference of these two `d` components?** (Or, if this is the preferred method... I'll just stick with it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach of obtaining that value:

1. Add **class** to the group that holds the bars

   ```
   .attr('class', function(d) { return d.key; })
   ```
2. Use the **class** added to fetch the respective column and get the corresponding value in the `mouseover` function using the `data` object (i.e. it'll basically end up getting the value from either `d.data['col_1']` or `d.data['col_2']`:

   ```
   var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')];
   ```

```js
var dataAsCsv = `date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575`;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#CE1126", "#00B6D0"]); // red and blue 

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month

var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
                  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year

var formatNum = d3.format(",")

var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv, function(d, i, columns) {
   for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
})

data.forEach(function(d) {
  //console.log(parseDate(d.date));
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
var barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(data.length+1);     

data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });


x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

var max = x.domain()[1];
var min = x.domain()[0];
var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

x.domain([min,datePlusOneMonth]);

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
z.domain(keys);


// the bars 
g.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
  .enter().append("g").attr('class', function(d) { return d.key; })
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {

  //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
  var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + barWidth / 2;
  var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + height / 2;

 var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')];
  //Update the tooltip position and value
  d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")                       
    .select("#value")
    .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 

  d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")                       
    .select("#month")
    .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the value 

  //Show the tooltip
  d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

})
  .on("mouseout", function() {
  //Hide the tooltip
  d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);

});  


// x-axis
var axis = g.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0]
xYearAxis.tickValues([firstDataYear].concat(x.ticks()));

var yearAxis = g.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
.call(xYearAxis);

axis.selectAll("g").select("text")
  .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");
```

```css
#tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    #tooltip.hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    #tooltip p {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    rect:hover {
        fill:orange;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p><strong>Month: </strong><span id="month"></span><p>
    <p><strong>Value: </strong><span id="value"></span></p>
</div>
```